# send file socket C linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a problem about a server (call servera) that receive a file from another server end send it to the client. The problem is that client receive 0 as file size and so zero bytes of the file:

```
/* receive file size from serverB */

recv(s,&bytes,sizeof(bytes),0);

/* send file size to client */

send(file_descriptor,&bytes,sizeof(bytes),0);

bytes = ntohs(bytes);

/* receive (from serverb) and send immediately (to client)*/

while (total != bytes) {
    nread = read(s,&c,sizeof(char));
    if(nread == 1){
        send(file_descriptor,&c,sizeof(c),0);
        total += nread;
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: To help diagnose the problem, I suggest getting Wireshark and looking at the traffic.

Comment: Check result of `recv`. It can be less than what you want (or negative on error). Also, learn about multiplexing syscalls like `poll`. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: How Can I utilize poll for receive and send as soon I have a single bytes in receive buffer?

Comment: You should almost never receive or send one-byte messages.

Comment: Also, compile with `-Wall -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Everything could be wrong.

You *must* check I/O calls for errors before relying on side-effects, otherwise you will get unpredictable results.

In your case, perhaps the first `recv()` fails, leaving `bytes` uninitialized at 0.

Also, the loop reading a single byte at a time is *very* inefficient, and still fails to check that it manages to send that byte (`send()` can fail in which case you need to re-try).